# Getting 403 Error with Priority integration

Tags: priority-web-sdk

I'm trying to integrate with Priority REST API and using 
https://prioritysoftware.github.io/restapi/#Service_Root_URL for this.
But when I'm trying to call some API's (for example https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/odata/Priority/tabmob.ini,3/usdemo/ACCOUNTS) I'm getting the error - **API cannot be run for this form**.
May someone explains to me what does exactly this means? Is there some permission problems?

Comment: Try running your request within https://www.getpostman.com/ and see if you encounter any issues there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message says that the system administrator hasn't exposed this form in Odata.
accoding to https://prioritysoftware.github.io/tryit (which is not working currently), only few forms were enabled: ORDERS, CUSTOMERS and AGENTS

Comment: Thanks, but a little bit late) Now I know that I needed to set flag "Available for API" for all required forms in FORMLIMITED